# Spring security role access, log in

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am having some issues implementing spring security, in particular the roles USER and ADMIN. I want each role type to redirected to its respective page /user and /admin. I have read countless tutorials and each one seems to be a little different than the last one and it's all very confusing. I was wondering if someone could define what I need to do as I dont think I am too far off with what I have done so far. The issue at the moment is that It does not redirect as per say, I do not think it's creating a session as when I try to retrieve any Prinicipal.getName() after login its always null. Is there anything other than this I am missing? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Pretty much the whole application bar the register feature, userRepo and views.

**public class UserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {**

```
@Autowired
UserRepo userRepo;

public UserDetailService(UserRepo userRepo){
    this.userRepo=userRepo;
}

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    //Find a user by username
    User user = this.userRepo.findByUsername(username);

    //Check if it's null
    if(user == null) throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
    //if not then return user detail with arguments
    else return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), getAuthorities(user));
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public static Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(User user) {
    // make everyone ROLE_USER
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new GrantedAuthority() {

        @Override
        public String getAuthority() {
            if (user.getRole().equals("ROLE_USER")) return "ROLE_USER"; 
            else return "ROLE_ADMIN";
        }
    };
    grantedAuthorities.add(grantedAuthority);

    grantedAuthority = new GrantedAuthority() {

        @Override
        public String getAuthority() {
            return "ROLE_USER";
        }
    };
    grantedAuthorities.add(grantedAuthority);
    return grantedAuthorities;
}
```

**@Service
public class UserServices  {**

```
@Autowired
private UserRepo userRepo;

//User register service
public void register(User user) {       
    //Encrypt password
    user.setPassword(BCrypt.hashpw(user.getPassword(), BCrypt.gensalt()));
    user.setRole("ROLE_USER");
    this.userRepo.save(user);               
}

//Used to add admin accounts on boot
public void adminOnBoot(User user) {
    user.setPassword(BCrypt.hashpw(user.getPassword(), BCrypt.gensalt()));
    this.userRepo.save(user);
}

//Return the list of users available
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    return this.userRepo.findAll();     
}

//Check if user exists by a username
public Boolean existsByUsername(String username) {
    return this.userRepo.existsByUsername(username);
}

//Check if user exists by an email
public Boolean existsByEmail(String emailAddress) {
    return this.userRepo.existsByEmail(emailAddress);
}

//Login user by the login forms username and password
public User loginUserByForm(LoginForm loginForm) {      
    User user = this.userRepo.findByUsername(loginForm.getUsername());      
    if(user != null && BCrypt.checkpw(loginForm.getPassword(), user.getPassword()))
        return user;

    else return null;
}
```

**@Controller
public class LoginController {**

```
@Autowired
private UserServices userService;

//LOGIN PROCESS - NO NEED FOR SEPERATE VIEW
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String verifyLogin(@Valid @ModelAttribute("loginForm") LoginForm loginForm, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

    User user = userService.loginUserByForm(loginForm);
    if(user == null) {

        //Add a model attribute for an error
        model.addAttribute("loginError", "notNull");

        //Passing the no. of registered users
        model.addAttribute("users", userService.getAllUsers()); 
        model.addAttribute("userCount", userService.getAllUsers().size()); 

        return "index";
    }

    //create the HttpSession
    request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);

    //Passing the no. of registered users
    model.addAttribute("users", userService.getAllUsers()); 
    model.addAttribute("userCount", userService.getAllUsers().size()); 
    model.addAttribute("username", user.getUsername()); 

    //TO DO
    return "admin";     
}

@RequestMapping("/logout")
public String verifyLogout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null){    
        new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
    }
    return "redirect:/login?logout";

}
```

}

**@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{**

```
@Autowired 
private UserRepo userRepo;
@Autowired
private CustomAuthenticationHandler authHandler;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceBean());
}

@Override
public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
    return new UserDetailService(userRepo);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
             //CSS FILES AND IMAGES
            .antMatchers("/css/**", "/img/**", "/js/**").permitAll()
             //PAGES FOR ALL PEOPLE
            .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/register/**").permitAll()
             //PAGES FOR ADMIN
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
             //PAGES FOR USERS
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAuthority("USER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
        .loginPage("/")
        .failureUrl("/?error")
        .and()
        .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    ;
}
```

}

**public class CustomAuthenticationHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {**

```
@Autowired
UserRepo userRepo;

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                    Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    User user = userRepo.findByUsername(authentication.getName());

    session.setAttribute("user", user);
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    if (user.getRole().equals("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
        response.sendRedirect("/admin/");
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("/user/" + user.getUsername());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your role definition:

in your **WebSecurityConfiration** your are sing **ADMIN**

```
.antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
```

But you are looking for ROLE_ADMIN to redirect to /admin

```
user.getRole().equals("ROLE_ADMIN")
```

Same with USER, you are looking for **USER** but you have defined **ROLE_USER**

Regards,

Comment: I have changed it to the following `.access("hasAuthority('USER')")` and still does the same, it's reaching the .failureUrl now.

Comment: Can you post the log issue?, Did you try loggin as admin?

Comment: Hi Guys --- fixed

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: Issue was that I didn't have my own implementation of an authenticate method, so it wasn't working. Just needed to add that and configure it as the authentication provider in the security config. I've posted what I've changed. Thanks for response!

Answer (score -1):

After many hours I've finally managed to get it working. For anybody with similar issues with custom log in forms (not j_spring_security_check..)I set up a new **CustomAuthenticationProvider.java**

```
@Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        User user = userRepo.findByUsername(authentication.getName());

        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        if(user != null) return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, getAuthorities(user));
        return null;
    }
```

I think added it into Security Config as follows ...

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(cap);
}
```

Simple fix really but confusing with so much differing information.
Regards,
Ben